# Move column data from parent to child table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a parent and child table, I need to move column information from the parent column to the respective child column.

```
CREATE TABLE public.parent
(
  id character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  surname character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT parent_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.parent
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TABLE public.child
(
  id character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  childname character varying(255),
  parentid character varying(255),
  surname character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT child_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT child_parentid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (parentid)
      REFERENCES public.parent (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.child
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I have a surname column in parent table, I need to move that data to the respective child.

what I've done so far,

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
   t_curs cursor for 
      select * from parent;
BEGIN
    FOR t_row in t_curs LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '%', t_row;
        update child set surname = (select surname from parent where id =  t_row.id) ;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But with the above example, the last parent surname in the iteration is being updated to all the child tuples.

Is there another approach to do this?

Comment: You don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL for this

Comment: @Shiva any luck?

Comment: Yeah. that works. I have made it complicated unnecessarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really need a PL/pgSQL for this? I believe a simple `UPDATE` would suffice:

```
UPDATE public.child
  SET surname = p.surname
FROM public.parent p
WHERE parentid = p.id;
```